# Asynchronous method call in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, storyboard

We have such a situation. We have a canvas, on which some ammount of figures are rendered. It may be 1 or many more (for example thousand) and we need to animate their translation to another location (on button click) using storyboard:

```
internal void someStoryBoard(figure someFigure, double coordMoveToValue)
{
    string sbName = "StoryBoard_" + figure.ID;
    string regName = "figure_" + figure.ID;
    try 
    {
        cnvsGame.Resources.Remove(sbName);
        cnvsGame.UnregisterName(regName);
    } 
    catch{ }
        someCanvas.RegisterName(regName, someFigure.Geometry);
        var moveFigureYAnimation = new PointAnimation();
        moveFigureYAnimation.From = new Point(someFigure.Geometry.Center.X, someFigure.Geometry.Center.Y);
        moveFigureYAnimation.To = new Point(someFigure.eGeometry.Center.X, coordMoveToValue);
        moveFigureYAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
        var sbFigureMove = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(sbFigureMove, regName);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(sbFigureMove, new PropertyPath(Geometry.CenterProperty));
        sbFigureMove.Children.Add(moveFigureYAnimation);
        cnvsGame.Resources.Add(sbName, sbFigureMove);
        sbFigureMove.Begin();           
    }
```

Figures are stored in list. We are calling this StoryBoard using for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<listOfFigures.Count; i++)
    {
        someStoryBoard(listOfFigures[i], someCoord);
    }
```

But here's the problem: if we have a little amount of figures - code completes quickly. But if ammount is big - there is a delay after a button is clicked and before the figures begin to move.
So, here's the question: is it possible to call someStoryBoard method asynchronously? Is next algorithm possible -> When someStoryBoard is called it begins to move figure instantly, not waiting for whole for loop to complete.?

Answer (score 1):

You can add actions into Dispatcher queue by calling `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`. You can also specify dispatcher priority, depending on your requirements.

Please note that moving thousands of items can't be reliably fast, so you may need to rethink the drawing logic. If even *starting animation* is slow, it's highly likely *animating* won't be fast enough too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use async/await modifier

```
async internal Task someStoryBoard(figure someFigure, double coordMoveToValue)
```